# Tempered distributions/Shwartz space on $\cup_{n>1}R^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, integration, functional-analysis

I have an application where I need to work with the shwartz space and its dual with underlying space $\cup_{n\geq 1}R^n$. I know only about the case when the underlying space is $R^n$. Please let me know whether it is possible to work with the space $\cup_{n\geq 1}R^n$ or not. Kindly give me a useful reference.